# Error: Type 'UIButton.ButtonType' has no member 'submit'

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibutton

I was asked to try and get an old repository for an iOS app to compile, and am getting this error from the below code:

```
//SubmitButton.swift
@objc enum ButtonType: Int {
    case submit
    case response
    case accept
    case decline
    case label
    case survey
    case create
}

class SubmitButton: UIButton {
    private let source: [ButtonType: [String]] = [.submit: ["Submit consult", "Submitting", "consult submitted"],
                                                  .accept: ["Accept consult", "Accepting", "consult accepted"],
                                                  .decline: ["Decline consult", "Declining", "consult declined"],
                                                  .response: ["Reply"],
                                                  .survey: ["Report Outcome", "Submitting", "Outcome reported"],
                                                  .create: ["New consult", "Creating New consult", "New consult"]]
    public var type: ButtonType

...
...
...
}
```

Using Xcode 10.0, app is written in swift 3.

Unfortunately I don't know Swift and this is my first encounter with an iOS app. Figured I'd ask on here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `ButtonType` inside `SubmitButton` the code is referring to the predefined `UIButton.ButtonType` which is not the enum that we see in the code above.

Please rename the `ButtonType` `enum` to a different name and it should work:

```swift
//SubmitButton.swift
@objc enum CustomButtonType: Int {
    case submit
    case response
    case accept
    case decline
    case label
    case survey
    case create
}

class SubmitButton: UIButton {
    private let source: [CustomButtonType: [String]] = [.submit: ["Submit consult", "Submitting", "consult submitted"],
                                                  .accept: ["Accept consult", "Accepting", "consult accepted"],
                                                  .decline: ["Decline consult", "Declining", "consult declined"],
                                                  .response: ["Reply"],
                                                  .survey: ["Report Outcome", "Submitting", "Outcome reported"],
                                                  .create: ["New consult", "Creating New consult", "New consult"]]
    public var type: CustomButtonType
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  ButtonType is an instance property, so changing name solves it!

Comment: @candyline anytime :)